# Joining and grouping Django querysets

Tags: python, django, django-orm

```
m1 = myModel.objects.filter(...)
m2 = myModel.objects.filter(...)

n1 = m1.values("date").annotate(car_crashes=Sum('car_crashes') * 1).values("date", "car_crashes")
n2 = m2.values("date").annotate(car_crashes=Sum('car_crashes') * 2).values("date", "car_crashes")
```

With this code, I get in n1 and n2 two querysets:

```
<QuerySet [{'date': datetime.date(2008, 4, 1), 'car_crashes': Decimal(1.000)}, ... ]>
<QuerySet [{'date': datetime.date(2011, 4, 1), 'car_crashes': Decimal(2.000)}, ... ]>
```

Please note that they might not be of the same size and some dates might be in one queryset but not the other.

How can I group these 2 querysets on the `date` field and sum `car_crashes`?

I'm trying this:

```
(n1 | n2).annotate(car_crashes=Sum('car_crashes')).values("date", "car_crashes")
```

and this

```
n1.union(n2).annotate(cc=Sum('car_crashes'))
```

but

> Cannot compute Sum('car_crashes'): 'car_crashes' is an aggregate

Answer (score 0):

Use the `union` operator:

```
qs3 = m1.union(m2)
qs3.annotate(car_crashes=Sum('car_crashes')).values("date", "car_crashes")
```

I'm not sure why you couldn't use m1 and m2 like shown rather than n1 and n2.

[Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#union) on union.

Comment: in n1 I multiply the sum by 1, and in n2 I multiply by 2. If I aggregate everything with no discrimination, this effect is lost.

Comment: .union as used before your edit works, but then I can't "group by" (with annotate), and it gives me the same error as above: Cannot compute Sum('car_crashes'): 'car_crashes' is an aggregate